# Microsoft Access cannot add records join key of table not in recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, addition

I know this is a repost, I have done my research on everything possible and I couldn't find anything to assist nor help me with my current problem. No matter how many times I re-create my Query or Form, I just can't seem to get it to work correctly. if I run my Query, I will get the correct information displayed, but when it comes to adding information through a custom form I made, I get this error -> `"cannot add records join key of table not in recordset"`.

My current Query, incase you wanted to see. I only access vendorNoID from the vendor table. I require all the information from the rest of the tables.

[image]

I am able to enter information in this form for tbl_address and tbl_addressType, but I get the error for vendor / purchaseOrder. Any reason whats causing this?!?!

[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your field `Vendor #` bound to tbl_purchase_order? If not, do so. Your `PO #` should be provided by an autovalue and should not be editable. Where's the connection to MySQL. That's something very different to MS Access.

Comment: I removed MySQL you were right on that one. I know my PO# is auto generated, but I just want the form to work before I play with the functionality. VendorID combobox -> record source = vendorID

Comment: The selected value got to be bound to [tbl_purchase_order].[vendorID]. It's got to be the same as you did with the address_typeID.

Comment: Thank you so much! I dont understand why my address_typeID has [ ] around it, while my vendor didn't? I would think it is auto generated since  it came from a query

Comment: Can you post the answer, so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected value of the vendor combobox got to be bound to [tbl_purchase_order].[vendorID]. To the table, where the selected value is the foreign key.

It's got to be the same as you already did with the address_typeID.

Answer (score 0):

> The selected value of the vendor combobox got to be bound to [tbl_purchase_order].[vendorID]. To the table, where the selected value is the foreign key. (@VMai)

In my opinion, open the Query Builder of Form (as picture below), then add column [tbl_purchase_order].[vendorID]

[image]
/

Cause I don't have enought reputation for write comment, so I write down here.
Hope it help ! ^^