# Microsoft Access - Combo Box - cannot add record, join key of table is not in recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

No matter how many tutorial, guides, or example I try to learn from; I can't seem to figure out how to make mine work. Its almost like a hit and miss when it comes to it. I got it working on some forms but I can't seem to get it working on others. Is there a trick to getting a combo box working; That I am missing?!

for example in my vendor form.

frm_vendor

```
   tbl_vendor  ->      tbl_address    ->     tbl_addressType
PK vendorID         PK addressID          PK addressTypeID  
FK addressID        FK addressTypeID
```

I am able to create a combo box which allows you to select the addressTypeID <- no problem

`control source = addressTypeID`

`row source =SELECT [tbl_addressType].[addressTypeID], [tbl_addressType].[addressType] FROM tbl_addressType;`

`row source type = Query/Table`

`bound to column = 1`

`limit to list = 1`

`not editable`

But on this new form, I can't see to get it working.

`control source = addressTypeID` seems to be invalid and gives me a warning.

When you create a form base off a query. Should I be including every PK / FK in this query even thought I wont be displaying it, so the form can understand the links?

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, if you need to display data through a combobox, you will need to bind that combobox to some data from the query, so that when the form is open on a particular record, it can set the value of the combobox (here, `addressTypeID`), which in turn will display the value you want from another table (in this case, `tbl_addressType.addressType`).

In tis particular case, what you are trying to achieve is actually not very clear and that may be one of the reasons you can't get what you want: if you can't define the problem completely, then you can't find a solution.

What is it you need to show exactly?
You list 3 different tables that have some related information, but it's not clear what is the role of `tbl_addressType` in this.
Maybe if you had a screenshot of the form it may help?

One point regarding your database naming convention: I think the fact that your PK and FK are named the same is part of the confusion.
If you were to adopt something like this, it may make things a bit clearer:

```
Vendor       ->   Address          ->   AddressType
PK ID             PK ID                 PK ID
FK AddressID      FK AddressTypeID
.. VendorName     .. AddressTitle
```

All Primary keys are named `ID`. Foreign keys follow the convention `ForeignTableName+ID`.
This makes the relationships unambiguous.

Now, your Vendor table is bound to a form:

```
 frmVendor.RecordSource = SELECT ID, AddressID, VendorName FROM Vendor
```

So now, let's say we want to display the Vendor's `AddressTitle` and let the user change the Vendor's address to another one by selecting it from the combobox:  add a combobox to the `frmVendor`, name it `cbAddress`:

```
cbAddress.ControlSource = AddressID
cbAddress.RowSource     = SELECT ID, AddressTitle FROM Address
cbAddress.RowSourceType = Table/Query
cbAddress.BoundColumn   = 1      ' Address.ID is bound to Vendor.AddressID
cbAddress.ColumnCount   = 2      ' Two columns: ID and AddressTitle
cbAddress.ColumnWidths  = 0;3    ' Width 0 for the ID column will hide it
```

And you are set.

When your form displays a Vendor record, the combobox will also display the corresponding Address' Title.
If your `frmVendor.RecordsetType` is `Dynaset`, then if the user selects another address from the combobox the `Vendor.AddressID` will be updated to the selected `Address.ID`.

Now, I still have no idea what you want to do with the `AddressType` table.

Comment: tbl_addressType contains a field called addressType which contains Vendor / Shipping / Billing / Customer. Since I had multiple address field repeating in tables; I decided to create a generic address table, to allow me to assign the address / type.

But in my case, the user isn't selecting his address, hes only selecting the type of address he will be assigning to the vendor.

Comment: You most probably do not need to normalise the addressType. Just store the addressType in a `Address.AddressType` field that will contain the actual value (eg _Billing_). Then just use the `AddressType` table as a lookup table. Going overboard with data normalisation will bite you in the end: it makes queries more complicated and, in some cases, offers no benefits if the data is a simple lookup value.

Comment: But I don't want the user to have any input. Are you suggesting to hard code the values inside my combo box?

What about my other tables for example, YarnType / YarnSize. Which only hold one value, but contains over 1000 records.

Comment: If the user is selecting the AddressType to be assigned to the Vendor, then it's obviously a property of the Vendor and the Vendor table should have an `AddressType` field. You can then repeast exactly what I have shown above but using your `tbl_addressType` as the rowsource of the combobox, and the `Vendor` table's new field `AddressType` as the Rowsource.

Comment: By using `addressType` as a look up field, I can only display what has ever been store in `addressType`. If the database was clear / clean one day. There would be nothing to display, until I hard coded in 4 fake address with the types `Vendor / Billing / Shipping / Customer`. This doesn't seem right to me or am I over thinking this?

Comment: I'm suggesting that, instead of using `Vendor.AddressTypeID`, you instead use `Vendor.AddressType`. You most probably do not need to store an `ID` for simple values. Same for your YanType/YarnSize: if these are pre-defined constants (meaning they don't change much over time, if ever), then you can tables to list them all (so the user can select the right one during data entry) but copy that value in the main table instead of copying an ID and then being forced to build multiple `INNER JOIN` queries to get back the value to display: just store the value to display directly in the first place.

Comment: But this is exactly how all other systems work: all systems have these lookup tables that are usually only used to let the user select the right data. Someone has to put that data in them once then forget it. Imagine a list of countries. You can have a table that list all 3-letter country codes, bind that to a combobox so the user can select the right one during data entry, but you don't necessarily need to store a FK CountryId in the Vendor table. Just store the country code directly. It's not like it's an information that is likely to change over time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58249/discussion-between-renaud-bompuis-and-joshua-dalley).

Answer (score 1):

The RowSource for the combo box determines where the data comes from to fill the list with values, this list can be from anywhere in the database.

The ControlSource is the bit that maps the combo box selected value to the query that the form is bound to, i.e. the name in the ControlSource needs to be a field that exists in the RecordSource for the form.

So, in your new form, you need to make sure the query you have based the form on has got a field called addressTypeID.

Comment: But it doesn't seem right, since I thought a query should be the fields you want to display. Having a surrogate PK/FK in the query seem un productive.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @Rikalous

> you need to make sure the query you have based the form on has got a field called addressTypeID

Hope this link can help:
[Microsoft Access cannot add records join key of table not in recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893504/microsoft-access-cannot-add-records-join-key-of-table-not-in-recordset/43121431#43121431)